# Experiment dropping electrons into glass of protons

Tags: entropy, particle-physics

So, when you drop dye into a glass of water the dye spreads out.

Now I realize you cant simply replace the water in the glass with protons (or a pure concoction of electrons) but I am wondering...

What is the closest real world experiment to doing just that: mixing a drop of electrons with a glass of protons, or vice versa.

Comment: Charging a metal? Electrons are said to be in a "sea" of electrons. Maybe you cant track the dropped electrons but surely they will spread randomly. What about plasma? They are more free maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This experiment is not possible, i.e. you cannot make a glass of only protons or a glass of only electrons because of the electromagnetic repulsion, they cannot be a liquid. A liquid requires chemistry

They can be a gas though, and the [LHC is creating a type of proton gas](http://www.lhc-closer.es/1/3/10/0) to get the protons for the beams. To get [hydrogen gas into](http://iopscience.iop.org/0368-3281/4/5/305)   [a plasma phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_%28physics%29) takes energy, and the temperatures are high:

> A set of closely-related devices for generating a highly-ionized hydrogen plasma is described. In each device a hydrogen plasma is created in a cylindrical tube immersed in an axial magnetic field of from 4 to 20 kG. The plasma is formed by a switch-on ionizing wave, driven from an external capacitor bank. In a typical tube 14.6 cm dia. and 86.4 cm long, with a magnetic field of 15 kG, an ion density of > 5 × 1015 cm-3 is attained in hydrogen of initial atomic density 6.6 × 10^15 cm^-3. The temperature of this plasma is between 10,000 and 30,000°K, and the plasma decays in several hundred microseconds by a volume-recombination process.

So it is neither simple nor stable like dye in water.  Elementary particles can be understood with quantum mechanics tools. The classical mechanics everyday intuition is not appropriate.